# Difference of two decimal values returns negatives, I need a floor of zeroes

Tags: sql, db2

I have a simple query that gets 2 percentages and then the difference between those 2 percentages

```
select
   round(t.priorDate * 100.0 / nullif(t.priorTotal, 0), 2) as priorPercent,
   round(t.currentDate * 100.0 / nullif(t.currentSales, 0), 2) as currentPercent,
   (round(t.currentDate * 100.0 / nullif(t.currentSales, 0), 2))-(round(t.priorDate * 100.0 / nullif(t.priorTotal, 0), 2)) as percentageDiff
```

from t;

This works fine but for the final upload of this data I need only positives or zeroes in that `percentageDiff` column so I want to set a floor of zero on that so that if it's negative (below zero) it just converts to zero.

Is there a standard for that in DB2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `greatest()`:

```
 greatest(0, (round(t.currentDate * 100.0 / nullif(t.currentSales, 0), 2))-(round(t.priorDate * 100.0 / nullif(t.priorTotal, 0), 2))) as percentageDiff
```

Comment: I have tried that but unfortunately I still get the negative numbers

Comment: @TomN. . . . And only non-positive numbers.  That was a "duh" moment.  You want `greatest()`.

Comment: Ha! I didn't even realize that existed, I was just looking for a MAX equivalent. That got it perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Since `greatest()` and `max()` are synonyms, why not suggest `max()`?

Comment: @WarrenT . . . `max()` and `greatest()` are not synonyms.  One is an aggregation function that accepts one argument and the other a scalar function that accepts multiple arguments.

Comment: @GordonLinoff... "The GREATEST scalar function is a synonym for the MAX scalar function." per Notes on Knowledge Center reference pages [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0052623.html?pos=2) or [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzscamax.htm).  But in the aggregates section, the synonym note is not there. So `MAX()` can be used as an aggregate or scalar, whereas `GREATEST()` can only be scalar.  Why bother ever using `GREATEST()` when `MAX()` is all you need?   (K.I.S.S. principle)